# Bars Charts & json

Tags: d3.js

I'm new dev d3js. I get value for bar in json [{},{}]? Help me. My code

```
[{value: 11}, { value: 111}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8fU5/

Thank you.

Comment: Please take the time to construct a question and show what you have tried. This makes it much more likely for more people to be able to help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems.

1. You reference `names.length` but names is undefined.  I think you meant `json.length`
2. You call `chart.selectAll("rect").data(data)` but data (the parameter) is undefined.  I think you meant `data(json)`
3. You are using scales directly where your data are not values in the domain they are expecting:

   ```
   chart.selectAll("rect")
       ...
       .attr("y", y)
       .attr("width", x)
   ```

   This only works if the data for the selection has values in the domain of the scale.  In this case, your data are objects where the `value` and `name` properties are in the domain of the scales, so:

   ```
   chart.selectAll("rect")
       ...
       .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.name); })
       .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
   ```
4. Similar issue for your text nodes:

   ```
   chart.selectAll("text")
       ...
       .attr("x", x)
       .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d) + y.rangeBand()/2; } )
       ...
       .text(String);
   ```

   Instead, you need to explicitly access the object properties:

   ```
   chart.selectAll("text")
       ...
       .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
       .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.name) + y.rangeBand()/2; } )
       ...
       .text(function(d){return d.name;});
   ```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Smrm3/